# Call PHP Function and Create PHP Session when AJAX Response Parameter is True

Tags: php, ajax, parameters, call

how i can call a PHP Function and Create PHP Session when AJAX Response Parameter is True?

Comment: call another ajax after getting response from first ajax

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? As far as I understand, you asking how can you do something on serverside when client gets the response. Do as Satish says, make another ajax call.

Comment: give some javascript code where you are calling ajax..so that we can tell you properly